# How elevate the alert in react native-paper?

Tags: react-native, alert, react-native-paper

I want to  shown an alert but my alert make to my app down scroll like this
[alert image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsEzY.png)
i would like show that alert on the center and elevate it.

i tried with this css, but does not worked nothing

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  elevatedElement: {
    zIndex: 3000000, 
    elevation: 3000000, 
  },
})
```

this is my code of the alert

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Paragraph, Dialog, Portal, Provider } from 'react-native-paper';

const Alert = ({ show, setShow }) => {


  return (
    <Provider>
      <View>
        <Portal>
          <Dialog visible={show} >
            <Dialog.Title>Alert</Dialog.Title>
            <Dialog.Content>
              <Paragraph>This is simple dialog</Paragraph>
            </Dialog.Content>
            <Dialog.Actions>
              <Button onPress={setShow}>Done</Button>
            </Dialog.Actions>
          </Dialog>
        </Portal>
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Alert;
```

and i am using that component like this

```
return (
    <><Alert show={true} />
    <Background>
       <RightButton goRight={logout} />
      <Logo />
      </Background>
      </>
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/portal.html) for the `Portal` usage:

> Portal allows rendering a component at a different place in the parent tree. You can use it to render content that should appear above other elements, similar to Modal. It requires a Portal. Host component to be rendered somewhere in the parent tree

So if you want to render the `Portal` on top of other elements like a modal you should use the `Portal.Host`:

**Note:**Try to implement the`Portal` component as the first element of `Alert` component without using the `View` element as below:

```
import { Portal } from 'react-native-paper';

// rest of the codes ...

return (
    <Portal.Host>
      <Dialog visible={show} >
        <Dialog.Title>Alert</Dialog.Title>
        <Dialog.Content>
          <Paragraph>This is simple dialog</Paragraph>
        </Dialog.Content>
        <Dialog.Actions>
          <Button onPress={setShow}>Done</Button>
        </Dialog.Actions>
      </Dialog>
    </Portal.Host>
  );
```

No need to set the `zIndex` or `elevation` style properties for this component.